# Display result of curl in a already existing div on the page

Tags: php, curl

I have a php page which makes curl request and gets a string in result

```
 function changePassword($oldPassword,$newPassword,$newPasswordCnf)
 { 

    //Get the user
     $loginUser = @$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pos = strpos($loginUser, '@');
    $position = $pos+1;
    $user = substr_replace($loginUser, 'ad.', $position, 0);
    $url = "http://127.0.0.1:13000/".$oldPassword."/".$newPassword."/".$user."/";     
    $curl_xv = new CurlRequest();         
    set_time_limit(60);    
    $output_message = $curl_xv->Request ( $url );
    //print($output_message);


}
```

and there is a  on the page and I want to display the $output_message in that div. How to do it?

Comment: So are you making an asynchronous call to the PHP script which then makes the curl call?  It is really unclear what your use case is here and what the specific problem is.

Comment: So, the user will be unable to use any characters that have special meaning in URLs in their passwords or username?